# How can I display my animated svg file in the android application?

Tags: java, android

i have a animated svg file, this; http://cbutopluluk.com/wait-sound.svg
How can show this file at android app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AnimatedSvgView). It's very easy to use. Follow the instruction given in the library description.

Don't forget to add

```
implementation 'com.jaredrummler:animated-svg-view:1.0.6'
```

to your app-level Gradle.